# Pip update error "Cannot call rmtree on a symbolic link"

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to update Jinja2 on my Synology DSM using pip command and I'm getting this error below.

```
root@Miranda:~# pip install -U Jinja2
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cffi/model.py:526: UserWarning: 'point_conversion_form_t' has no values explicitly defined; next version will refuse to guess which integer type it is meant to be (unsigned/signed, int/long)
  % self._get_c_name())
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Collecting Jinja2
  Using cached Jinja2-2.11.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (125 kB)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site
-packages (from Jinja2) (0.23)
Installing collected packages: Jinja2
  Attempting uninstall: Jinja2
    Found existing installation: Jinja2 2.8
    Uninstalling Jinja2-2.8:
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: Cannot call rmtree on a symbolic link
```

Any idea on what's happening? It seems that when the system tries to remove the old installation, the error occurs and exits the update process.

PS: I saw this happening when I tried to update other packages.